# Dual array correspondance

Tags: arrays, tcl

I just found myself in a position where I have two arrays in Tcl.

I'm given `$W_Array` and `$P_Array`.

I need to traverse through one array not knowing what the size of each one is before hand, and execute a command only when there is a value for both arrays. Yes the array lengths could be different.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: It appears you really mean lists, which are more like what other languages call arrays.  Tcl arrays are hash maps.  You can take the length of a Tcl list but not a Tcl array without converting it.

Comment: If you can clarify whether you mean lists (a,b,c) or arrays (a=X, b=Y, c=Z), the answers will probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by "a value for both arrays", but tcl's `foreach` supports iteration over multiple arrays at once... so you can say e.g.
`foreach w $W_Array p $P_Array {
    if {$w == $val && $p == $val} {
      ...
    }
 }`

When the arrays are not of the same length, `foreach` will return all values from the longest array and the empty value `{}` for the missing elements in any shorter arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers jumped to using lists, I presume you mean [Tcl's array](http://wiki.tcl.tk/532), which are also called hash maps or associative arrays.

I think you're asking for something like:

```
array set a1 {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5}
array set a2 {z 0 x 1 b 2 e 99}
foreach n [array names a1] {
  if {[info exists a2($n)]} {
    puts "Do something with $a1($n) and $a2($n)"
  }
}

# FOREACH LOOP RESULTS IN THESE TWO PRINTOUTS
Do something with 5 and 99
Do something with 2 and 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `llength` command to find out if the arrays contain a value.

```
if {[llength $W_Array] > 0 && [llength $P_Array] > 0} {
# Do something
}
```

Comment: I don't think this comes close to answering the actual question. Admittedly the question is slightly vague.